# "ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed" when using raster created from NetCDF

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, netcdf, zonal-statistics, rioxarray

My code creates a geoTiff from a NetCDF and then I'm trying to compute `zonal_stats()` from a raster file I created from a NetCDF. I end up getting `ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed` at the last step of my short code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import rioxarray as rxr
import rasterstats as rs
import xarray as xr
import rioxarray

# Open the world-wide NetCDF
file_nc=xr.open_dataset("wglc_timeseries_05m.nc")
NC_Data = file_nc.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)

# Slice the first date
export_raster=NC_Data.sel(time=NC_Data["time"].values[1])
export_raster.rio.to_raster("temp.tif") 
reimported_raster = rxr.open_rasterio("temp.tif").squeeze()

# Load african centroids to prepare buffers
centroids_points = gpd.read_file("centroids.json", driver="GeoJSON")
centroids_poly = centroids_points.copy()                
centroids_poly["geometry"] = centroids_points.geometry.buffer(0.1)
centroids_poly.to_file("plot_buffer.shp")

# Collect buffer stats
buffer_light = rs.zonal_stats("plot_buffer.shp",
                                    reimported_raster.values,
                                    affine=reimported_raster.rio.transform(),
                                    stats="count mean")
```

I have the feeling this might be related to the negative numbers here, but I'm unsure how to fix this.

```
reimported_raster.rio.transform()
Out[445]: 
Affine(0.08333333333333318, 0.0, -179.99999999999966,
       0.0, 0.0833333333333333, -89.99999999999997)
```

For replication, here are the downloads of [wglc_timeseries_05m.nc](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3q9641p2frb4hl8/wglc_timeseries_05m.nc) and the [centroids.json](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7utw4gvuni8c3u/centroids.json)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it's related to a positive number, the y pixel dimension should be negative (pixel coords are top->bottom, but map coords are bottom->top), but it isn't. This is why a negative dimension is being reported - i.e. rasterstats thinks the shape is (-2160, 4320) instead of (2160, 4320).

The affine transform isn't being read correctly by the default xarray engine.  Using the rasterio engine in following works for me:

```
file_nc = xr.open_dataset("wglc_timeseries_05m.nc", engine="rasterio")
etc...
reimported_raster.rio.transform()

Affine(0.08333333333333316, 0.0, -179.99999999999966,
   0.0, -0.08333333333333329, 89.99999999999997) # <--- Note fifth element (transform[4]) is negative.
```

As a bonus, you don't need to write out to a tif on disk if you don't want to:

```
# Collect buffer stats
buffer_light = rs.zonal_stats("plot_buffer.shp",
    export_raster.to_array().squeeze().values,
    affine=export_raster.rio.transform(),
    stats="count mean")

buffer_light
[{'mean': 0.0, 'count': 5}, {'mean': 0.0, 'count': 4}, {'mean': 0.005268027121201157, 'count': 5}, {'mean': 0.0, 'count': 5}, {'mean': 0.0, 'count': 5}, {'mean': 0.0, 'count': 5} etc...
```

And with just rioxarray:

```
# Open the world-wide NetCDF
ds = rxr.open_rasterio("wglc_timeseries_05m.nc")
ds = ds.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326")

# Slice the first date
ds0 = ds.sel(time=ds["time"].values[0])

# Load african centroids to prepare buffers
centroids_points = gpd.read_file("centroids.json", driver="GeoJSON")
centroids_poly = centroids_points.copy()
centroids_poly["geometry"] = centroids_points.geometry.buffer(0.1)
centroids_poly.to_file("plot_buffer.shp")

# Collect buffer stats
buffer_light = rs.zonal_stats(
    "plot_buffer.shp",
    ds0.squeeze().values,
    affine=ds0.rio.transform(),
    stats="count mean")

print(buffer_light)
```